# Huge memory comsuming while using Python multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, pandas, memory, multiprocessing

When I use the multiprocessing in the python, I always meet the trouble of memory issue.Below is the code that I wrote:

1. I have many many files need to process, each file only 100kb, but the total size would be like 30GB around.
2. I have a function that read the file with pandas DataFrame, and then return a dictionary after processing the dataframe, the dict only contains limited information, thus the size is very small. Single dataframe will be deleted after the process.
3. Multiprocess Pool.apply_async() is applied to process each dataframe in parallel, and then the returned results are append to a list.
4. The information that I need will be extracted from list by .get().

The problem is the memory increases a lot while I using Multiprocess, could be as much as 20GB before the process dead. However since I drop the file for each running the memory should be very low, which has been tested without the use of Multiprocess.

I also have some code to monitor the memory, looks everything good, I have no idea about where the memory goes.....

**My python code**

```
            files = natsort.natsorted(glob.glob(path))
            cores = int(0.8 * multiprocessing.cpu_count())
            l = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cores)

            for file in files:
                p = l.apply_async(self.single_run, args=(file, dict_record))  # 异步执行
                results_list.append(p)

            l.close()
            l.join()

        import sys

        local_vars = list(locals().items())
        for var, obj in local_vars:
            print(var, sys.getsizeof(obj))

        for result in results_list:
            for k, v in result.get().items():
                dict_stat_record[k].extend(v)
```

I use a halfof the files to test the memory comsuming, verything loos good....
self 48
dict_record 1176
stat_columns_list 304
obj_np_list 336
np_columns_list 376
results_list 514560
path 137
dict_record_list 56
files 31888
cores 28
l 48
file 163
p 48
sys 72

This has been bothering me for days, I tried some ways but none of them works, including limit maxtasksperchild=1000 or p.wait.

Is there anyone met this situation? I appreciate if anyone can help...

I'm still having the issue...